# jQuery .keypress & .keydown .which

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard, keypress, keydown

Ok so what is the difference in .keypress and .keydown/.keyup? At present I am using .keydown which returns a .which value of 38 for my key, now if i change it to .keypress it returns a value of 109 for that same key. What is the difference and why are the values different for the same key?

Comment: Different browser's should result in different event which's but not different key commands

Comment: I have a json object with every key event and each divided by browser, i'll post it too a fiddle real quick with all three keypresses and we can test this out, gimmie like 10 mins

Answer (score 23):

If you press a button it fires a `keydown` and releasing it fires a `keyup`. The `keypress` usually comes between those two.

`keydown` and `keyup` talk about which ***key*** has been changed. `keypress` tells which ***character*** that key represents.

Note that this is all browser-dependent!

See [this article about the differences between the key events as implemented on various browsers](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html).

Answer (score 21):

I'll be d$%^@d, there really is a difference with keypress and all this time I never realized. lol

See my fiddle and try something like the letter "r"

http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/NePCm/

Somehow I never paid attention to this

> Found more info:
>
> http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html
>
> "The two properties are `keyCode` and `charCode`. Put (too) simply, `keyCode` says something about the actual keyboard key the user pressed, while `charCode` gives the ASCII value of the resulting character. These bits of information need not be the same; for instance, a lower case 'a' and an upper case 'A' have the same `keyCode`, because the user presses the same key, but a different `charCode` because the resulting character is different.
>
> Explorer and Opera *do not* support `charCode`. However, they give the character information in `keyCode`, but only with `onkeypress`. `onkeydown` and `-up` `keyCode` contains key information."

Comment: Yea, so this is why I am confussed as to why?

Comment: well as jbl pointed out in his answer, [this page](http://javascript.info/tutorial/keyboard-events) describes the problem just a little bit, but it still doesn't seem to answer the question in whole. Maybe I read the page wrong, but at one point it still points out the charcode as being pulled on both, simply one reutrns a different value. Perhaps a look in some old js doc will find the answer.  I'm looking now, also gonna rewite my object to include the keypress differences

Comment: although i would suggest avoiding keypress as it doesn't fire as predictable events as keydown and keyup

Answer (score 14):

You should read the following post :
http://javascript.info/tutorial/keyboard-events

> Keydown triggers on any key press and gives scan-code.
>   Keypress triggers after keydown and gives char-code, but it is guaranteed for character keys only.

Answer (score 9):

In normal cases, go for `keyup`:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e){
  console.log(e.which);
});
```

Reasons:

1. `keydown` keeps firing when user holds the keys down, while `keypress` and `keyup` fire only once.
2. `keypress` doesn't detect special keys (e.g. `SHIFT`), `keydown` and `keyup` do.

Answer (score 2):

KeyPress happens after KeyDown. So you can use KeyDown to determine what key it is, then KeyPress to disallow that character.