# Disable zero as first letter in <input>

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below code disables `0` as the first character in `#foo`.
However, you can bypass this by typing `123`, then drag to select `123` and putting `0`. (or `ctrl+a` on input)

Is there a way to block this scenario?

```js
 $('input#foo').keypress(function(e){ 
  if (this.value.length == 0 && e.which == 48 ){
   return false;
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="foo" />
```

Comment: you may wish to check out [jQuery mask](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) plugin

Comment: You still need server side validation, just as a reminder

Comment: the easy no-js way: `<input pattern="^[^0]\d+">`

Comment: @dandavis ie10+, but still, nice!

Comment: @andrew: you can polyfill before that and still get all the advantages of the new system. certainly much cleaner than manually binding brittle dom/js connections from an external script.

Comment: Seems like bad UX. If you type something into a textbox, you expect something to show up. Wouldn't it be better to just "santize" the data the user inputs and remove the leading zeros before persisting the data?

Comment: @pkr298: Or if we *insist* on using silly Web N.0 techniques, turn the input box red or something.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would handle the input, propertychange, and paste events. Then use regex to match for anything that begins with 0 and replace the current value with the value minus the leading 0.

http://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/5qxwpv6h/

```
$('input ').on('input propertychange paste', function (e) {
    var val = $(this).val()
    var reg = /^0/gi;
    if (val.match(reg)) {
        $(this).val(val.replace(reg, ''));
    }
});
```

Bug fix reported by Kevin/Updated per recommendations of canon:

http://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/5qxwpv6h/2/

```
$('input').on('input propertychange paste', function (e) {
    var reg = /^0+/gi;
    if (this.value.match(reg)) {
        this.value = this.value.replace(reg, '');
    }
});
```

Comment: All the other answers talking about key events are completely ignoring the issue specified in the question (dragging text inside input element). oninput event is the right way for this case.

Comment: Bug: Type `123000` and then delete `123`.  You're left with `00`.  I'd suggest using the regex `^0+`.

Comment: @SeanWessell So, instead of updating your regex you've decided to reach for a while loop. On top of that, you're instantiating a new jQuery object for every single loop condition _and_ its body. So, **1.:** why are you using `$(this).val()` instead of `this.value`? It's unnecessary overhead. **2.:** If you _insist_ on `$(this)`, why aren't you caching your jQuery objects? **3.:** Why are you looping instead of just updating the regex? I'm worried over the fact that this answer has attracted so many upvotes.

Comment: @canon Updated answer. I use SO to learn from and help others and thank you for the pointers on how to write cleaner code!

Comment: While we're on the subject, you might consider [`RegExp.prototype.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) rather than [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match). You're not really doing anything with the string value returned from `match()` other than banking on its truthy/falsey coerced value. `test()` simply returns `true` or `false` outright.

Answer (score 2):

This could work:

```
$('input#foo').keyup(function(e) {
    if((this.value+'').match(/^0/)) {
        this.value = (this.value+'').replace(/^0+/g, '');
    }    
});
```

The only thing that could bother you with this solution is that zero is displayed for a second and then deleted, since we are using `keyup` event.

[A quick demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nxrgbw4c/2/)

Comment: you can hold 0 and it will result in `000000..`

Comment: it de-selects now. (ctrl+a)

Comment: updated once again, but the accepted answer is better.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the `keydown` jQuery event as opposed to the `keypress` event. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191621/jquery-keypress-keydown-which) some move info on the difference between the two. Try regex to get rid of leading zeroes:

```
$('input#foo').keydown(function(e){ 
    this.value = this.value.replace(/^0+/, '');
});
```

Comment: this still allows you to enter a leading 0 it just won't allow anything after it. It also doesn't allow you to highlight and replace the text in the textbox. If you try it will append what you type to the string that was originally there.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the fixed version :

```
<input id="foo" />

$('input#foo').keyup(function(e){ 
     if(this.value.substring(0,1) == "0")
     {
        this.value = this.value.replace(/^0+/g, '');             
     }         
});
```

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ewmb1yq9/4/

Comment: his completely disables 0 as input

Comment: you can hold 0 and it will result in `0000...`

Answer (score 1):

Accept only numeric values not prefixed by zero. Supports <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>:

```js
var escapeKeys = [8, 46];
$('input#foo').keyup(function (e) {
    if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, escapeKeys) != 0) {
        if ((this.value + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)).match(/^[1-9][0-9]*$|^$/) != null) {
            this.lastValidValue = this.value + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
        } else if (this.lastValidValue) {
            this.value = this.lastValidValue;
        } else {
            this.value = "";
        }
    } else {
        this.lastValidValue = this.value;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="foo" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch the changes to the input's value (including the changes made by dragging part of the text for example), you can watch the [`input`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp) event.

```js
$('input#foo').on("input", function(){
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="foo" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a "submit" event to validate whether it's entered or not, regardless of how it could have gotten there:

```js
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
  if ( $( "input:first" ).val() != 0 ) {
    $( "span" ).text( "Validated..." ).show();
    return;
  }
  $( "span" ).text( "Not valid!" ).show().fadeOut( 1000 );
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p>Type 'Anything but 0' to validate.</p>
<form action="javascript:alert( 'success!' );">
  <div>
    <input type="text">
    <input type="submit">
  </div>
</form>
<span></span>
```

jQuery's working is example is last on page here (https://api.jquery.com/submit/)

NOTE: The most important part will be to add the "event.preventDefault()" action, because that will keep the form from accidentally submitting.

Comment: this answer is out of scope.