# How change this mask javascript function to avoid start with zero?

Tags: jquery, mask

Please, where I can change this mask function to avoid the user type 0 (zero) as a first number?

This is a mask function to format the input at this format:

```
(99) 9999-9999 or (99) 99999-9999
```

Once here in Brazil the celphone has now 9 digits and normal phones 8 digits. But the city code (between parentheses) could NOT start with 0 (zero), otherwise will mess up the phone number.

```
// telefone com 9 digitos           
var SPMaskBehavior = function (val) {
  return val.replace(/\D/g, '').length === 11 ? '(00) 00000-0000' : '(00) 0000-00009';
},
spOptions = {
  onKeyPress: function(val, e, field, options) {
      field.mask(SPMaskBehavior.apply({}, arguments), options);
    }
};

$('#telefone').mask(SPMaskBehavior, spOptions);
```

Here's [the mask link](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html)

Comment: The mask functionality you are using may not support this I would look into adding a regex function that would have [1-9] for the first part of the pattern.

Comment: Right, i found this reg pattern, but I dont know how to insert this in the mask function [LINK REG PATTERN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32614989/disable-zero-as-first-letter-in-input)

Comment: You could put it inside the OnKeypress behavior and then if we regex doesn't match you can return false. I won't use some thing like myRegex.test(val))

Comment: Thank you Judson. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the first digit entered is a zero...

That is easy to check using a simple `if` condition.
You just need to check the second character of the value, first is `(`.

If it is a zero, remove it... And, optionnaly, notify the user.

```js
// telefone com 9 digitos           
var SPMaskBehavior = function (val) {
  return val.replace(/\D/g, '').length === 11 ? '(00) 00000-0000' : '(00) 0000-00009';
},
    spOptions = {
      onKeyPress: function(val, e, field, options) {
        if(field.val()=="(0"){
          console.log("NO! No zero to begin.");
          field.val(field.val().substr(0,1)); // Removes the 0
        }
        field.mask(SPMaskBehavior.apply({}, arguments), options);
      }
    };

$('#telefone').mask(SPMaskBehavior, spOptions);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.11/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

<input id="telefone">
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly what I need.