# Jquery: An alternate method for fromcharcode() to convert integer to character

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm coding a chat box. And the Characters that I enter, is not reflected as it is.

This is basically the code I'm using.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".entry").keydown(function(event) {
        console.log(String.fromCharCode(event.which));
    });
});
```

And so when I type (lower-case) "a", console tab shows me "A".

special characters will not get reflected unless I create separate condition for it.

Could someone help me with a different function which does it all by itself, and returns a string as entered by the user. Or a different approach to this challenge all together. Thanks.

Actual code - chat.js

```
var str='';

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".entry").keydown(function(event) {
         console.log(event.which);
         if (event.which === 13 && event.shiftKey === false) {
             console.log(str);
             event.preventDefault();
         } else {
             var c = event.which;
             str = str.concat(String.fromCharCode(c));
         }
    });
});
```

So basically the every character entered would get concated to the string. and Enter key would dump the text to console.

Comment: Do you have any special filters applied for chat box which converts the chars?

Comment: No i dont think so .

var str='';

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".entry").keydown(function(event) {
        console.log(event.which);
    if (event.which === 13 && event.shiftKey === false) 
    {
        //$(".entry").css("background-color", "blue");
        //alert($(document.getElementById('entry1').innerHTML));
        console.log(str);
        event.preventDefault();
    } else {
        var c = event.which;
        str = str.concat(String.fromCharCode(c));
        //console.log(String.fromCharCode(c));
    }
    });
});

Comment: this is the actual code ...

Comment: Add this above code in the questio

Comment: And BTW "entry" is the name of the class of the textarea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's seems that trying to get the value of `event.which` in `keydown` event could lead you to a wrong ascii code (What you need to pass to `String.fromCharCode`).

> See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10192144/3879872

I don't know if it fits your needs, but you could try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".entry").keypress(function(event) {
        console.log(String.fromCharCode(event.which));
    }); 
});
```

(Note the use of `keypress` instead of `keydown`)

EDIT: Added working Demo

```js
var str = '';

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".entry").keypress(function(event) {
    console.log(event.which);
    if (event.which === 13 && event.shiftKey === false) {
      console.log(str);
      event.preventDefault();
    } else {
      var c = event.which;
      str = str.concat(String.fromCharCode(event.which));
    }
     console.log('Formated Text', str);
  });
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea class="entry"></textarea>
```

Comment: Worked like a Charm. Thanks :)